# Getting an error saying "Unable to cast token to token"

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a button that when you click it, a menu pops up and you can build things, but on line 5, I'm getting the error "Unable to cast token to token", which I've never heared of before. Here's the code:

```lua
local B = script.Parent
local BF = script.Parent.Parent.BuildFrame

B.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
    BF:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.837, 0, 0.359, 0), Enum.EasingStyle.Quad, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, 1)
end)
```

Comment: Looks like you have EasingStyle and EasingDirection in the wrong order.